# obs-md-header-spliter: script error "unterminated regexp" in a 2 year old script (maybe new gawk syntax)?

Tags: windows, awk, cmd, markdown

**hey there :)**

I need help with the following script for gawk which I thankfully found on this github: https://github.com/dxcore35/obs-md-header-spliter

I installed gawk successfully and the env var is working as well.

In the readme there is the following script-line;

```
awk -F, '/^# /{h=substr($0,3);} {print > ( h ".md")}' $Book.md$
```

between the two `$$` I inserted the path as stated in the readme.md (without `""` I guessed)
**but** it isn't working, unfortunately I am getting this error:

```
awk: '/#
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

**if** I simply delete the two invalid chars `'`, the following error shows up:

```
awk: /#
awk:  ^ unterminated regexp
```

Any ideas? I am quite new to gawk so I can't find the issue for 60 min straight xD

Comment: Looks like you're on Windows but trying to use Unix quoting (`'`) instead of Windows (`"`) around your script. Google something like `Windows awk quoting` as I think there's other things you need to do too beyond just changing the quote character.

Comment: indeed - thank you - did not found the other syntax errors so far ;(